# Question on operator norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

> In the space $C[0,1]$ with the norm $\|x\| = \sup\limits_{0 \leq t \leq 1} |x(t)|,$ we consider the linear functional $$F(x) = \int_{0}^{1} x(t) f(t)\ dt,$$ where $f$ is a given continuous function. Prove that $$\|F\| = \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|\ dt.$$

I have shown that $$\|F\| \leq \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|\ dt.$$ For the reverse direction a hint has been provided.

> **Hint** $:$ For any integer $n,$ we set $$ 
> \varphi_n(y)= \left\{
>   \begin{array}{lr} 
>       n y & |y| \leq \frac {1} {n} \\
>       1 & y \geq \frac {1} {n} \\ -1 & y \leq - \frac {1} {n}
>       \end{array}
> \right.$$
>
> It is easy to see that $\varphi_n$ is continuous on $\mathbb R.$ Take $$x_n (t) = \varphi_n (f(t)).$$

It is clear that $\|x_n\| = 1,$ for all $n \geq 1.$ I think what the hint suggests us to do is to show that $$|F(x_n)| \to \int_{0}^{1} |f(t)|\ dt\ \text {as}\ n \to \infty.$$ But I am unable to show that. Do anybody have any idea about it?

Waiting for some suggestion!

Comment: Can't you just expicitly calculate $F(x_n)$ and then evaluate the limit?

Comment: @QuantumSpace I have tried to compute it but I got stuck.

Comment: @uniquesolution Yeah sorry there was a typo. Fixed it now.

Comment: @uniquesolution I don't know how to cheat. I have the question in front of me. I have overlooked the typo. I thought that it was rightly written. As soon as I saw it I deleted the comment immediately. Don't blame anybody before getting  to know him well. I have never ever cheated to anybody else. Don't make me feel angry.

Comment: @Phibetakappa Are you using Lebesgue or Riemann integral?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Riemann integrals.

Comment: Riemann or Lebesgue doesn't matter. We work with continuous functions here. Perhaps the better question is: does the OP know dominated convergence theorem from measure theory? It is not necessary for this problem though.

Comment: @QuantumSpace I don’t understand your comment. DCT from measure theory with Riemann integral (even for continuous maps) would be really artificial.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net But the Riemann integral and the Lebesgue integral coincide for continuous functions...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There holds $x_n(t)f(t)\to\lvert f(t)\rvert$ as $n\to\infty$ (for every $t$) and $\lvert x_n(t)f(t)\rvert\le\lvert f(t)\rvert$ (for every $t$ and $n$). Now use Lebesgue's dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: Do you mean $x_n(t)f(t) \to \mathbf {1}_{|f| \gt 0} |f(t)|$ as $n \to \infty\ $?

Comment: $\mathbf 1_{\lvert f\rvert>0}\lvert f(t)\rvert=\lvert f(t)\rvert$ for every $t$, because if $\lvert f(t)\rvert=0$, both sides vanish.

Answer (score 0):

Let $C_n = \{x\in [0,1]: |f(x)|<=1/n\}$.  Split the integral $F(x_n)$ into two parts - over $C_n$ and over the complement of $C_n$.  $C_n$ is a closed subset of $[0,1]$.  Over $C_n$, you're integrating $nf^2(x)$, but $|f(x)| <= 1/n$ there, so the integral is bounded by at most $n/(n^2)$ times the measure of $C_n$, which is at most 1.  So this part goes to zero.  Over the complement of $C_n$ you're integrating $|f(x)|$ which is the integrand whose integral you're trying to estimate.

Oh, and BTW it's not true that $||x_n|| = 1$ for all $n\ge 1$, only for sufficiently large $n$, because $|f|$ could be completely smaller than $1/n$ for some finite number of $n$.

Comment: I have approached in the same way that you prescribed in the first part of your answer. But I still have two integrals namely $$\int_{f \geq \frac {1} {n}} f(t)\ dt - \int_{f \leq -\frac {1} {n}} f(t)\ dt.$$ This two integrals can be merged together to write $$\int_{|f| \geq \frac {1} {n}} |f(t)|\ dt.$$  For your second part you are right. In fact we should also assume that $f \not\equiv 0.$

Comment: Please review the definition of $\varphi_n$.  The 2nd part does not split like that.  It's just the absolute value of $|f|$ (notice the multiplication by $-1$).

Comment: why not? I don't see any mistake.

Comment: Well, fine, you corrected it.  But the 2nd part is great, because as n goes to $\infty$, the set $|f|\ge 1/n$ increases to the support of $f$ which is what you need.  Outside the support $f$ is zero anyway.  It just helps.  You can continue and integrate zero outside the support to cover the whole $[0,1]$ interval.  Also, if $f$ is identically zero, the statement of the theorem is trivial.  If $f$ is non-zero at even a single point, then for sufficiently large $n$, $||x_n|| = 1$.